# Creating a calendar event on windows live REST API

Tags: windows-live

I'm always getting time-outs (60sec) after making a post to create an event.

URL: https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/events
JSON: {
    "id": "",
    "name": "Google 3",
    "description": "mychild event",
    "calendar_id": "calendar.c988c1d9bf3dcf4b.adasdasdeqe3231q23",
    "start_time": "2014-04-30T08:30:00-05:00",
    "end_time": "2014-04-30T09:30:00-05:00",
    "is_all_day_event": false,
    "visibility": "public"
}

I pass the access_token on the http headers with the format: Authorization: Bearer + AccessToken.

I've successfully created this very same event using the ISDK.

What I'm doing wrong? Any hint?

Tks,